# About installing new desktop environment on Ubuntu

Tags: desktop-environments, touchscreen, surface

I am a new user of Linux. I recently install surface linux kernel following [this](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup) so that i can use touchscreen on my surface pro. Now i want to try a new desktop environment (maybe KDE) on it. So here is my question:

1. Will installing new desktop environment affect to surface linux kernel which i installed before. Do i have to install it again from scratch
2. For some personal reason, i cant use any other linux distributions except Ubuntu. Will KDE work well with ubuntu? (i saw in some post people say that KDE work better with kubuntu). If not, i would appreciate if someone can suggest me some great desktop environment like awesome,cinnamon,etc...

Comment: Operating systems & software work on various levels. The kernel is the closest software in the stack nearest your actual hardware. User applications the closest to the end-user. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS for example is available using two software stacks, the GA kernel uses the linux 4.15 kernel, the HWE now uses the linux 5.4 kernel. Kernel modules (commonly called *drivers*) of course being related to the kernel differ, but the end desktop, and user applications elsewhere in the stack are the same regardless of kernel in use.

Comment: Kubuntu uses the KDE desktop instead of the GNOME desktop found on Ubuntu desktop. KDE uses different libraries (Qt5 & KDE Frameworks 5) to GNOME which uses GTK3, so those are changed to. The different toolkits & libraries also mean Kubuntu comes with different applications to Ubuntu Desktop with GNOME.. but that's all a very different level to the kernel & any software nearer the hardware level of your machine.   FYI:  The box I'm writing this on has 3 desktops installed on a Ubuntu base... desktop & user applications are not impacted by kernel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have installed KDE and now running two desktop environment at the same time(like you said, desktop was not impacted by kernel so i can use screentouch normally). The only problem is the application on plasma conflict with gnome that leading to some screen scale and dock issue. Is there any way to fix that ?

Comment: I don't know your issue, however KDE uses Qt and follows Qt guidelines, conventions of where settings & configs go, GNOME however uses a different set of rules (GTK conventions) so changes made in one environment may not be seen in the other, this isn't conflict, just different environments. It maybe you've made changes in one, but not the other (ie. keeping the two in sync) so when applications or desktops using different settings are on the display at the same time, they aren't playing well together because you've given them different setups to follow. Keep configs in each matching..